# MS SQL find multiple columns in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Normally, I use this code to find a column in my table:

```
Use MyDatabase
Go
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name in ( N'String1') 
    AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Table1'))
BEGIN
    Print 'Column String1 exists in Table1'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Print 'Column String1 does not exist in Table1'
END;
```

We're updating the table and adding 56 new columns. How do I go about that without duplicating the code 56 times? It's just a quick error check to do after importing the new columns. Another thing I'd like to do is just print out the result only if the column isn't found.

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: 56 *extra* columns :| I hope you've got about minus 40 columns already!

Comment: It's a data warehouse.

Comment: In that case, carry on. You're nowhere near as many as you should have :)

Comment: There really isn't an easier way to check each column than to check each column. If you don't want to do anything when the column already exists just change your check to NOT EXISTS and drop the else.

Comment: Just create a temp table with the list of columns you want to check, and loop on it to execute this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a table containing all the 56 column names you want to check and then left join it against the management view:

```
DECLARE @cols TABLE
(
    column_name     varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO @cols
    VALUES ('col1'),('col2'),('col3')

IF EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM @cols c
            LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col ON col.COLUMN_NAME = c.column_name
                                                    AND col.TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
            WHERE col.TABLE_NAME IS NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Some columns are missing'

    SELECT c.column_name
    FROM @cols c
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col ON col.COLUMN_NAME = c.column_name
                                            AND col.TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
    WHERE col.TABLE_NAME IS NULL
END
```

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is functionally the same as `sys.columns`. I prefer it for being cleaner and have more info than `sys.columns`.